# Counting Values under specific conditions

Tags: ms-access, join, count

I am very unexperienced with SQL and I have the following problem: I have a table with transactions between a company and their vendors. Among a lot of other columns I have the transaction date and the vendor account code and the transaction date. What I need to do now is to check how many vendors are new, recurring and inactive given specific dates. So if vendor X shows transaction dates in 2013 and 2014, he would be a recurring vendor, if he shows only transaction dates in 2014, he would be a new one and only in 2013 an inactive one. Now I don't just need to compare 2014 to 2013, but also comparative dates with year end dates and so on. What I have done so far is create individual queries for everything, which is a lot of work and seems a bit inefficient. currently I would have the queries "DecToOct14" and "SepToJan14":

```
SELECT DISTINCT (vendor_account_cd)
FROM [Doc Year & Period]
WHERE Doc_Period > 9 AND Doc_Year = '2013';


SELECT DISTINCT (vendor_account_cd)
FROM [Doc Year & Period]
WHERE Doc_Period < 10 AND Doc_Year = '2014';
```

And then this one to show the actual result:

```
SELECT  
Count (*) 
AS Recurring_CY_Comp1
    FROM (
                 SELECT DISTINCT ( [Doc Year & Period].vendor_account_cd )
                 FROM [Doc Year & Period] 
                             INNER JOIN DecToOct14 ON [DecToOct14].vendor_account_cd = [Doc Year & Period].vendor_account_cd
                  WHERE [Doc Year & Period].Doc_Year = 2014 AND [Doc Year & Period].Doc_Period <=9
                );
```

The queries are working and delivering the desired results, but ideally I would like it all to be in one query and if that's not possible at least have all the counts in one like this:

```
SELECT  
Count (*) 
AS Recurring_CY_Comp1
    FROM (
                 SELECT DISTINCT ( [Doc Year & Period].vendor_account_cd )
                 FROM [Doc Year & Period] 
                             INNER JOIN DecToOct14 ON [DecToOct14].vendor_account_cd = [Doc Year & Period].vendor_account_cd
                  WHERE [Doc Year & Period].Doc_Year = 2014 AND [Doc Year & Period].Doc_Period <=9
                ) ,

Count (*) 
AS Recurring_Comp1_PY
    FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT ( [Doc Year & Period].vendor_account_cd )
                FROM [Doc Year & Period] 
                             INNER JOIN SepToJan14 ON [SepToJan14].vendor_account_cd = [Doc Year & Period].vendor_account_cd
                WHERE [Doc Year & Period].Doc_Year = 2013 AND [Doc Year & Period].Doc_Period > 9
                );
```

As I said, I am very new to this and am out of ideas. I could just build a query for every analysis, but in total it is going to be 24 different analyses and if I need one or two queries each, that is going to be a mess. The code is a bit of a mess too, since I am using MS Access, sorry about that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think it is bad idea to have separate tables for various months in a given year.

Comment: It probably is, I just didn't know how else to do it, since my only idea to check for recurring vendors was to use an inner join

Comment: I would use conditional aggregation here, but I won't attempt anything because it is hard to figure out what the tables are doing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is right. You should stop now and get the tables sorted out, or you will just continue to run into issues like this - and it will only get more worse and more ugly.

Comment: Well, conditional aggregation sounds like a good idea, but I have no idea how to write it so it only shows the vendors active in dec-oct 2014 and sep-jan 2014

Comment: @Gustav Well as you can see, all tables shown here are referring to "Doc Year & Period", which is the table that contains every single transaction. I just don't know how to use that information to get my results